# RabbitMQ - Send Data to another consumer

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I'm a neophyte with RabbitMQ use. I wanna know if it is possible to send data from a consumer to another.

Let me explain,

I want to implement the [Pipeline pattern](https://github.com/thephpleague/pipeline) to my application to pipe classes execution.

Example:

```
// payload = 20 (at the entrance)
$pipeline = (new Pipeline)
    ->pipe(function ($payload) {
        return $payload * 10;
    })
    ->pipe(function ($payload) {
        return $payload + 10;
    })
    ->pipe(function ($payload) {
        return $payload - 5;
    })
;
// payload = 205 (at the end)
```

What I want to do is to execute the first callback in a consumer, when it finished it send the computed data to the another consumer and so on. To finally have `205` as value for `$payload`.

I just wanna know if is it possible to do that with RabbitMQ ?

Thank a lot for your replies, :)

Comment: I'm currently reading [this](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html). If i got answers, I'll share here ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course. One rabbitmq client would simply be consumer and publisher at the same time, where each of the "functionalities" would be in two independent threads and each of them using their own channel.

Also please note that you are never sending a message to a consumer directly, rather to an exchange which routes the message (in certain ways) to queues bound to it. Consumers "attach" themselves to queue(s) and consume from them.